# MYSQL ordering by date (string)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a date column which is formatted like this: `28-15`.

The format for this is the first number tells which week, and the second one which year.

I have tried using `str_to_date(datecolumn, '%v-%y')` with no good results.
It orders the list BUT its not in the correct order.

I also tried concatting the datecolumn to make the string appear like this:

`01-28-15` (First is the day of the week) and using `str_to_date(datecolumn, '%w-%v-%y)`, with no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MySql [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

> You cannot use format "%X%V" to convert a year-week string to a date
>   because the combination of a year and week does not uniquely identify
>   a year and month if the week crosses a month boundary. To convert a
>   year-week to a date, you should also specify the weekday:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('200442 Monday', '%X%V %W');
```

For you case, you need to make assumptions about week day(for example monday) and century(for example 2000), then you can get date next way:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(datecolumn, ' ', 'Monday'), '%V-%X %W'), INTERVAL 2000 YEAR)
```